# Need help creating a Menu before a JFrame Calculator

Tags: java

So I have a Calculator which I made using Java for a school projects, in order to get more points I was requested to create a menu with instructions before the calculator shows up, and I can't think of a way on how to do it, so if anyone can help it would be great:

How it currently looks when run:
[image: How it looks when run]

And I have 2 classes the Main class which is used to run the program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new Calculator();
    }   
}
```

Along with the Calculator class which holds all the inner workings (this is a shortened version of the code):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    //Establish buttons 
    JButton b1;
    
    
    //establish label
    JLabel label;
    
    
    
    //establish double (for numbers) and string (for arithmetic and conversions)
    double ans; //answer of function
    double tans; //temporary number which is used to make the code work
    double num1; //inputed number
    double num2; //inputed number
    double Tnum1; //temporary number which is used to make the code work
    double Tnum2; //temporary number which is used to make the code work
    String arth; //a string version of num1 used to display on the label
    

    Calculator(){
        
    
        
        //All which has to do with Jlabel "label"
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200); //size of the label
        label.setVisible(true); //Makes the label visible
        label.setLocation(80, -80); //Location of label
        label.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 30)); //Font of text
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); //Alignment of text
        label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); //Alignment of text
        label.setText("Welcome");
        
        
        //All which has to do with button "b1"
        b1 = new JButton();
        b1.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50); //Size of button
        b1.setLocation(50, 50); //Location of button
        b1.addActionListener(e -> {label.setText("1");
                            if(num1 > 0) {
                            num2 = 1;
                            }else {
                                num1 = 1;
                            }}); //Sets num1 or num2 to the value 1                     
        b1.setText("1"); //Text in button
        b1.setFocusable(false); //Removes box outline from Button's Text
        b1.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 30)); //Sets font of text in button
        b1.setForeground(Color.white); //Foreground (text) Colour
        b1.setBackground(Color.darkGray); //Background colour
        b1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()); //Style / border of button
        b1.setEnabled(true); //Enables button to work
        
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(390, 500); //size of Frame
        this.setVisible(true); //shows the frame
        this.add(b1); //adds the button b1 to the frame
        this.add(label); //adds the label to frame
        ;
    }
}
```

I really hope someone is able to help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html) of `JFrame`, it has a method `setJMenuBar`; Oracle's tutorial: [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) is more detailed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a menu bar & menu, you can use `JMenuBar` and `JMenu`. To add items in the menu, use `JMenuItem`.

Here's an example code:

```
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String args) {
     
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame("Menu example");    // The base frame

        JMenuBar testMenuBar = new JMenuBar();    // The menu bar

        /*
         This is a JMenu, which we often see on the top of the frame.
         But you need to add something called JMenuItem to achieve
         the functions. Swing is just lazy.
        */
        JMenu testMenu = new JMenu("test");

        /*
         And this is the menu item that I juat said.
        */
        JMenuItem testMenuItem = new JMenuItem("test item");

        /*
         This step is very important! Remember to add an "ActionListener"
         using method addActionListener(). Because this is the core of your
         event handling system. When you click it, it will do what you
         want.
         Add it to the MenuItem!
        */ 
        testMenuItem.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Clicked!"))

        /*
         Then, all you need to do is to add these things together!
        */
        testMenu.add(testMenuItem);
        testMenuBar.add(testMenu);
        testFrame.setJMenubar(testMenuBar);

        testFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Then, you'll notice that when you click the inside menu item, the console prints "Clicked!".

Here is your improved code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    //Establish buttons 
    JButton b1;
   
    //establish label
    JLabel label;
    
    //establish double (for numbers) and string (for arithmetic and conversions)
    double ans; //answer of function
    double tans; //temporary number which is used to make the code work
    double num1; //inputed number
    double num2; //inputed number
    double Tnum1; //temporary number which is used to make the code work
    double Tnum2; //temporary number which is used to make the code work
    String arth; //a string version of num1 used to display on the label
    

    Calculator(){
       
        //All which has to do with Jlabel "label"
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);    //size of the label
        label.setVisible(true);    //Makes the label visible
        label.setLocation(80, -80);    //Location of label
        label.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 30));    //Font of text
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);    //Alignment of text
        label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);    //Alignment of text
        label.setText("Welcome");
        
        
        //All which has to do with button "b1"
        b1 = new JButton();
        b1.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);    //Size of button (&Location)
        //b1.setLocation(50, 50);    You don't really have to, 'cause location is already set in setBounds().
        b1.addActionListener(e -> {label.setText("1");
                            if(num1 > 0) {
                            num2 = 1;
                            }else {
                                num1 = 1;
                            }});    //Sets num1 or num2 to the value 1                     
        b1.setText("1");    //Text in button
        b1.setFocusable(false);    //Removes box outline from Button's Text
        b1.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 30));    //Sets font of text in button
        b1.setForeground(Color.white);    //Foreground (text) Colour
        b1.setBackground(Color.darkGray);    //Background colour
        b1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());    //Style / border of button
        //b1.setEnabled(true);    Buttons are originaly enabled.

        
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu infoMenu = new JMenu("info");
        JMenuItem infoItem = new JMenu("Instructions");
     
        infoItem.addActionListener(e -> ;);    // Write your code here.
       
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(390, 500);    //size of Frame
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);    // the menu bar of instructions menu.
        this.add(b1);    //adds the button b1 to the frame
        this.add(label);    //adds the label to frame
        this.setVisible(true);    //shows the frame
       
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new Calculator();
    }  
}
```

*P.S. You don't have to import Math. Just use Math.methods() and so on.
The compiler knows what you want to do. And make sure you write
"this.setVisible(true)" at last 'cause there are some compoments that can't
be normally displayed after that.*